# Android set lock screen wallpaper programmatically

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set android lock screen image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653954/how-to-set-android-lock-screen-image)

I was able to set wallpaper programmatically. Can I do that for lock down screen ? How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible from the standard API. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653954/how-to-set-android-lock-screen-image) previous answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

As the lockscreen wallpaper is not editable on Android, this is not possible from the offcial tools.

I guess that you have an HTC or some OEM customized phone, so you can maybe ask HTC for doc, but I really doubt they will give it to you!

Comment: Oh ok ..... anyways..... thanks for replying

Comment: saavn music application changing screen wallpaper when it is in lock state

Comment: That can be done with RemoteControlClient. But your app needs to be registered as a media controller.