# How to set android Lock Screen Wallpager via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wallpaper, lockscreenwidget

I see many people have asked about this problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653954/how-to-set-android-lock-screen-image), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071162/android-set-lock-screen-wallpaper-programmatically) and ... but I can not find any solution.
However, I see some [background app on playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ogqcorp.bgh) can do it.

My purpose is that I want to open intent for set lock screen wallpager like
[image]

This device is SamSung S2

Answer (score 1):

Generally there is no (proper) documentation on how to set the Lock screen Wallpaper. [Samsung](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=223124) doesn't allow it as far it goes.

In some Phones, we are able to see the Wallpaper we set through Wallpaper Manager purely dependent on the Device Stock OS. And we have no control over it specifically.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(mPath), "image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as: Home Screen"));
```

Comment: please, don't just post code as an answer, it is always better to explain why and what you are doing ;)