# How to find if the device has the Lock screen wallpaper capability in android?

Tags: android

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653954/how-to-set-android-lock-screen-image), I came to know that it is not possible to set the lock screen wallpaper programmatically even if the device has that capability. But I would like to know if there is any way that I could find out if the device has the lock screen wallpaper capability. (Like the one available in Galaxy S2 as shown below)

[image: lock screen wallpaper option]