# Android LockScreen customization

Tags: android, animation, locking, screen, lockscreen

Is there a way to change the lock screen in Android programmatically?
If yes, is it possible to create an animation within that view?

Comment: Android Jelly Bean adds support for lock screen widgets. Beyond those I don't know whether you can access it.

Comment: See..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653954/how-to-set-android-lock-screen-image

Comment: I mean, there are several apps which work like "Lock Screen". For example MagicLocker Main and Go Locker. How they achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change the lock screen in Android programmatically?

No, because there is only one lock screen. On Android 4.2, the *user* can add app widgets to the lock screen, if the user chooses. You can elect to create an app widget that can be added to the lock screen.

> If yes, is it possible to create an animation within that view?

Generally, no. App widgets are not normally animated.

Answer (score 0):

android doesn't officially supports it with a nice API , but there are some solutions for this problem . the best one that i can think of and that will work perfectly on all devices and android versions is this :

you can make an app that functions as a launcher , and ask the user to disable the lock screen.

this way , when the screen is turned off&on , your app will be able to be shown and do whatever it needs .

each time the app is being unlocked , it will send the intent of the home button to the real launcher the user has chosen .

of course , there are other solutions , but as i've tried , all of them have some kind of problem on some android devices and versions . they work by listening to the power off intent , and block the home button by using a flaw they've found in the android source code . you can never assume that it will work on all devices and android versions .

example of such apps are "[widgetLocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker)" and "[Picture Password Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TwinBlade.PicturePassword)"