# How to change the lockscreen wallpaper in android?

Tags: android, wallpaper, lockscreen

I want to change the **lockscreen** wallpaper of android. I was able to change home screen wallpaper through `WallpaperManager.setResource`

But not able to set **LockScreen Wallpaper**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now possible with the updated Android API in API Level **24**.

You have to provide the target **WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK** flag via the `setResource` method.

```
int setResource (int resid, int which)
```

See the updated [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setResource(int,%20int)) for the `WallpaperManager`

Comment: So it is not possible to use live wallpapers, right? I read the documentation and I only found options to bitmap.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: See Mikepenz's answer for API 24+.**

<s>According to CommonsWare (who generally knows what he's talking about), there's no such thing as a lockscreen wallpaper, and there's no way of changing the lock screen background through the API.</s>

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2654241/153225.

Answer (score -14):

1. Go to the **Main menu** and search for the icon **Wallpaper**
2. Tap on that icon. You will be provided with three options:

   - *Gallery*
   - Live Wallpaper
   - Wallpaper
3. Tap on the source from which you would like to select your new wallpaper. Choosing **Gallery** will bring you to your saved images and photographs.
4. Tap the  **Set Wallpaper**  button once you decide on your new wallpaper.

Comment: Also this does not specifically set the lockscreen background only the phones background.