# How to set full screen album art in lock screen?

Tags: android, lockscreen, albumart

I am making simple app like any music app and I want album art on lock screen of phone like in **Play Music** application of google when song is playing and your screen is locked and you are going to open it you will find such lock screen

[image: play music lock screen album art]

How can I do this? can you please suggest any good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer: [Set lock screen background in Android (like Spotify do)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281616/set-lock-screen-background-in-android-like-spotify-do)

And also this sample app written by google worked for me to understand what happens, it may also help you to understand about your music application. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/RandomMusicPlayer

EDIT: About the random music player, you need to create a new project and move the classes and resources to make it work simply.

Answer (score 0):

User MediaSessionCompat to set lock screen image.