# Is it possible to set Lockscreen background image programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to set lockscreen image dynamically in android. Is it possible to set the image dynamically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281616/set-lock-screen-background-in-android-like-spotify-do

Answer (score 1):

it s available on API24

```
WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setStream(inputStream, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
```

check [this reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#FLAG_LOCK)