# Android Set Lock Screen Wallpaper

Tags: android, android-developer-api, android-wallpaper

According to [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#FLAG_LOCK) I must have API > 24 to set the locked screen wallpaper and I only have 23.

However, both the [Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos) and [Pandora](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pandora.android) apps set my lock screen wallpaper

**Can anyone help me do one of the following?**

1. Set the lockscreen like Pandora?
2. Send an [intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html) to the photos app to set the lockscreen?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which Android version you have on the phone?

Comment: Android 6.0.1 (SDK 23)

Answer (score 0):

Technically there's no way to do that before API level 24.

In order to change the lock screen temporary, you need an application that has registered itself as a media controller. Media/Streaming players like "**Pandora**" uses "**RemoteControlClient**" In Android **4.+** and media "**Notification**" on **5.0+** to display information/change wallpaper on the lock screen.

See a detailed example in [Set lock screen background in Android (like Spotify do)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281616/set-lock-screen-background-in-android-like-spotify-do)

Comment: Thank you very much! I saw that detailed example too. Is there any way to send an intent to the app Photos with an imageURI and have the "complete action using" screen popup like in the first image above?