# Set wallpaper via Gallary app

Tags: android, wallpaper, lockscreen

i was looking around if it's possible to set Wallpaper for Lockscreen directly from android Sdk but unfortunately it's not available yet but how ever i have seen some apps able to do that via Stock gallary app as in the picture
is there a certain intent for gallary app to set A certain image as wallpaper ?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `Bitmap` as a wallpaper using the [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html). It defines a method [setBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) which allows you to set the bitmap as wallpaper.

However, to do that, you need the permission to set the wallpaper to be defined in the manifest.

`how can i send my bitmap to gallary`
You need to create a file with appropriate extension and then use the [compress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress) method to write it to that file.
Here is a quick code that I took from another answer on SO:

```
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm aware that you can set wallpaper by using wallpaper manager but it only works for home screen so lets say i already got the path to my image and it has .jpg extension so how i can send that image path to gallery app to set it as lock/home screen.Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a `Bitmap` that you want to store as a JPG, so set the constant in `compress()` to `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG`

Comment: You can set the lock screen image programatically but that is a security violation. You may want to have a look here : https://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/

More on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653954/how-to-set-android-lock-screen-image

Comment: And please note that `JPEG` are highly compressed images so if you have an image downloaded from the internet as a `Bitmap`, please do not expect a lot of compresion