# Android lock screen change wallpaper/background image

Tags: java, android, image, lockscreen

Is there any way to change background image on lock screen (Android devices. native Java code? No other functionality, just image change.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653954/how-to-set-android-lock-screen-image)

There is no "lock screen image" in Android. There most certainly is no "lock screen image" concept that is the same between stock Android, HTC Sense, MOTOBLUR, etc. This simply is not part of the Android SDK.

The project that Mr. Rijk points to is a security violation that pretends to be a lock screen replacement

My Thinking: The lock screen wallpaper settings are dependent on the TouchWiz launcher, and we don't provide the API for this.