# Change lock screen wallpaper While playing music in foreground

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am developing a android music application above API-16, one of my requirement is to change the lock screen wallpaper when my music application is running in foreground. This feature can be seen in google play music application like when music notification is displayed in the lock screen the album art can be seen as lock screen wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible from the standard [API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653954/how-to-set-android-lock-screen-image). See this previous answer to this question.