# Setting Android HomeScreen wallpaper only

Tags: java, android, wallpaper

How can I set the wallpapers of android programmatically for the options below:

- Set as HomeScreen Only
- Set as Lockscreen only
- Set as Homescreen and Lockscreen

Below is what I have So far but I can't figure out how I can set it for homescreen only.

```
private void setWallpaper(final int flagSystem) {

    Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(wallPaper)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        try {
                            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getContext());

                            int wallpaperHeight = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
                            int wallpaperWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

                            Point start = new Point(0, 0);
                            Point end = new Point(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

                            if (bitmap.getWidth() > wallpaperWidth) {
                                start.x = (bitmap.getWidth() - wallpaperWidth) / 2;
                                end.x = start.x + wallpaperWidth;
                            }

                            if (bitmap.getHeight() > wallpaperHeight) {
                                start.y = (bitmap.getHeight() - wallpaperHeight) / 2;
                                end.y = start.y + wallpaperHeight;
                            }

                            if (flagSystem == 0) {
                                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap, null, true);
                              

                            } else if (flagSystem == 1) {
                                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
                            } else {
                                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y), false);

                            }

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Wallpaper set successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set android lock screen image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653954/how-to-set-android-lock-screen-image)

Answer (score 2):

use `WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM` flag

```
manager.setBitmap(bitmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM);
```

Comment: WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM sets for both Home screen and lock screen. I want to set only for home screen.